# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix A = (1,2,0), (-1,-2,1), (2,4,1). I end up with the polynomial x^3-5x=0 and no exact solution.

Comment: Are those row or column vectors?

Comment: Your polynomial can be rewritten as $x(x^2-5)=0$, from where $x_1=0$, and $x_{2,3}$ can be easily found.

Comment: @user71671,  follow direction in the FAQ section to properly write mathematics here with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Your characteristic polynomial is right. You have at least one exact solution being x=0. Yhe other exact solutions are $\sqrt 5 $ and $-\sqrt 5$. This you can check easily.

You can also check this yourself by using wolframalpha.com. Type in {{1,2,0},{-1,-2,1},{2,4,1}} and you will get al the necessary information including the eigenvectors.

Comment: You can enter $\sqrt{5}$ using {} instead of ().

Comment: follow direction in the FAQ section to properly write mathematics here with LaTeX ,and @Ruslan: when there's one unique character under the square root not even {} is need: a simple space will do: \sqrt 5 = $\,\sqrt 5\,$

Comment: @DonAntonio well I do know this, just wanted to show that MrOperator was using incorrect symbols for taking number inside. And in fact, you can even drop the space and use \sqrt5 = $\sqrt5$.

Comment: Indeed so, Ruslan, but the space is general: if you want $\,\sqrt a\,$ you do need the space.

Comment: Indeed you are right. Was a bit distracted when typing this and got my brackets wrong. Thanks for the correction though.